# How can I pass parameters through an @EnvironnementObject router in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to build a router in my SwiftUI application that is based on an @EnvironmentObject. The thing is that I want to pass parameters sometimes (corresponding to an ID for example) to access the view specifically for the parameters passed on.

The router looks like this :

```
import SwiftUI

enum Route {
    case Index(objectId: String?)
    case User(objectId: String?)
    case Page(objectId: String?)
}

class Router: ObservableObject  {
    @Published var currentPage: Route = .Index(objectId: "")
}
```

Then I use the @Published value to update my currentPage variable and update the current view. This is here that I want to pass the parameter.

```
Button(action: { viewRouter.currentPage = .Page(objectId: id) }) {
    ...
}
```

Then in my Page view (which is the new current page) I wnat to use this parameter :

```
import SwiftUI

struct PageView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: Router
    var objectId: String?
    var body: some View {
        Text("Page \(objectId)")
    }
}
```

How do I achieve something like that ? Am I completely wrong about this parameters thing ? I don't really understand why my parameter is blank.

Thank you.

Comment: Not really clear what do you mean (or want to achieve)... you have both router and page id in `PageView`, so what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that the ID that I pass from the previous view isn't passed to my next view through the router.

Comment: @MathieuRios how do you define viewRouter in root view? Show that code too

Comment: In `PageView`, where are you getting `objectId` from? If you want the property stored in your `viewRouter`, you need to access `viewRouter.currentPage` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see in your code samples where you're injecting the `Router` class into the Environment. At the `@main` point of your app you can accomplish this like so;

```
@main
struct RunPlanner: App {

let router = Router()

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(router)
    }
  }

}
```

Then as Patrick Wynne said in the comments you should be able to access your `viewRouter.currentPage` property.